# nodejs handlebars, missing helper error

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I am trying to implement handlebars in a project.
My problem is that if i am running my project locally it works fine.
But when i am running it on deployment, it shows 
"Error: Missing helper: "is_about_me""

My HTML template is :-

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    {{#is_about_me is_about_me_filled}}
                    <td align="center">
                        <p style="margin: 0 0 10px 0; color: #727272;">+ <a href="{{orgDtls.org_url}}" style="font-size: 15px; color: #727272; text-decoration: none;">Add About Yourself</a> </p>
                    </td>
                    {{/is_about_me}}
                </tr>
</table>
```

and my helper is:--

```
var handlebars = require('handlebars');
    handlebars.registerHelper('is_about_me', function (isAboutMe, options) {
        if (isAboutMe === 0) {
            return options.fn(this);
        }
    });
```

Any help will be appreciated.

thanks, Shivam

Comment: Can you post the code for the server? In what file was the helper defined?

Comment: Why is `is_about_me_filled` a number? It looks like the value should be a boolean and you should replace your custom helper with the built-in #if block-helper.